# How to exclude some object properties from webpack bundle?

Tags: webpack

In my project I use webpack for bundling JavaScript and I have modules which export js-objects like:

```
module.exports = {
  name: 'Test',
  tableName: 'TestTable',
  properties: {
    id: {
      description: 'identifier',
      columnName: 'id'
    },
    title: {
      description: 'title or something',
      columnName: 'title'
    }
  }
}
```

These modules are used both by back-end and front-end. But I don't want to see properties like "tableName" and "columnName" in the webpack bundle. Is there a way to exclude them or their values, but preserve rest of module?

**UPD**. I think it is can be a kind of solution:

webpack.config.js

```
var webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
  entry: './index.js',
  output: {
    path: './build/',
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      P: JSON.stringify(true)
    })
  ]
};
```

index.js:

```
var entity = require('./entity.js');

console.log(entity.tableName)
```

entity.js:

```
module.exports = {
  name: 'test',
  tableName: !P && 'TestTable'
}
```

> webpack -p

output:

```
bundle.js:1 false
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use global constantst with `DefinePlugin`.

### DefinePlugin

The DefinePlugin allows you to create global constants which can be configured at compile time. This can be very useful for allowing different behaviour between development builds and release builds. For example, you might use a global constant to determine whether logging takes place; perhaps you perform logging in your development build but not in the release build. That’s the sort of scenario the DefinePlugin facilates.

### Example

```
new webpack.DefinePlugin({
    PRODUCTION: JSON.stringify(true)
})
if (PRODUCTION)
    //here you can have your conditional objects which you want to build or not
```

Answer (score 1):

IMHO this is not part of webpack's scope. However, you could add/remove members based on some `ENV` variables I guess.

Comment: Thanks for the tip!